# Is a flame whistle, pipe organ or flute possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, combustion

Could one arrange a simple candle or wick oil lamp in a way that it would make a sound while it is burning?  A simple device without a Sterling engine etc.

Does the rising hot air have enough energy to play a musical instrument?

Bonus if it could make a dual tone or warble for an alarm signal.

Comment: I dont know if dry air is enough, but there already exist steam whistles. For example whistling tea kettles, or old train whistles.

Comment: I suppose if one had two almost identical units adjacent to each other the beat frequency could be distinctive.

Comment: I was also thinking that a petrol or paraffin burner could power a whistle but the complexity is going too high.  I would have hoped for a disposable unit that has little of value.  Imagine a haunted hilltop that stops automatically after a few hours.

Comment: Google for "pyrophone."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Very interesting.  I wonder if a candle flame would work, this is close to what I was hoping for, something very simple.  If the pipe were long enough I suppose one could generate _fear_ inducing sub-sonics.

Comment: The haunted hilltop whistle reminds me of the natural nuclear fission reaction in Gabon. If the water boiled off and happened to cause a whistling noise at some point where it exited the ground...

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely!

The classic example is the [Rijke tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijke_tube), where a Bunsen flame (in modern versions) acts as an energy source. When the flame is placed at a location where the heat release can couple with the pressure nodes, it will amplify the acoustic waves and make it "sing." It's a fun experiment and can be done with a candle and a pipe at home (like the original setup).

Comment: Those are loud! If one is a bit careful one can use a wide cardboard tube.

Comment: This is amazing, never heard of it but it is old news.
Hmm, 1kW of electrical heat is a bit much.  I was thinking of a candle powered haunted house :-)  Can this be scaled down, I don't need a lot of noise.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. the propane-fueled radiant space heater in my shop exhibits a very strong resonance while the flame is on which is loud enough to interfere with conversation.

Comment: Looking for compact examples. Though your heater sounds antisocial.

Comment: it is antisocial. the only antidote is vodka.